# how to change class element in enumeration element in EA

Tags: enterprise-architect

In enterprise architect V10:

I have created a lot of class elements with stereotype enumeration and now I've discovered that there exists an enumeration element.
I found that it is possible to change the element type in a previous version of enterprise architect [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871161/change-class-element-to-interface-element), but is it still possible to do this in V10 and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the element in a diagram and then choose the menu option **Element|Advanced|Change Type** and select enumeration from the list. (tested in v11.1 but it will probably work in v10 as well)

Comment: Enumeration is not in the list, so this only works the other way around. (convert to class or entity) Any idea about getting Enumeration in this list?

Comment: @od107 Upgrade to v11.1 I guess. If you really need to do a lot of them, and you can't upgrade my might want to consider updating the database directly. (change the t_object.Object_Type to "Enumeration")

Comment: @od107 Oh, another thing you might want to try is to export the package containing the enumerations to xmi, and import them again. I believe that will transform classes with stereotype <<enumeration>> into "real" enumerations.